# Rising higher; ascending

Tags: orthography

I had in mind for a long time that: `Highering` is a correct word for the title definition.

However I doubt this is a common used word even if I find the definition in the 1913 Webster dictionary http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/highering

> Highering \High"er*ing\, a.    Rising higher; ascending.    [1913
>   Webster]

as most of the automatic correction on my computers says it's wrong (including google suggest)

Comment: 2 minutes and already a downvote ... can somebody explain why ?

Comment: *Highering* would be an unusual word to hear or see in print. This might seem illogical since *lowering* is an everyday gerund of the verb *to lower*. As far as I know there is no verb *to higher*. The verb you need is *heighten*. So *After heightening the ceiling, the room took on an altogether more spacious appearance* - also figuratively *the government wants to heighten the barriers for EU migration into the UK)*.

Comment: First line of the "What topics can I ask about here?" is "Word choice and usage" which is definitely the subject of my question.
I do not know the validity of my source (webster 1913), but the fact this word exists at some point in the literature makes my question more than valid.

Comment: @suməlic The word has, hitherto, existed, though as the OED points out it is now rare. The poet Tennyson used it *1872   Tennyson Gareth & Lynette 4   To sweep In ever-highering eagle-circles up To the great Sun of Glory.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not a native speaker, I would definitely advise against using this word. (Even if you are a native speaker, I advise against it; but native speakers can consult their intuition to try to tell if something sounds too bad.)

As the 1913 Webster dictionary mentions, it was used by the well-known poet [Tennyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred,_Lord_Tennyson) in the phrase

> In ever highering eagle circles.

I'd guess this historical literary significance is the only reason why it's listed in that dictionary. (The Oxford English Dictionary also lists it, but the OED tries to list every word, even archaic and dialectal ones.)

As a present-day native speaker, I don't remember ever hearing it used, and it sounds wrong to me. I would always use "rising (higher)" or "ascending."

To me it just looks like the present participle of a verb "higher", but the OED classifies it as an adjective and considers the intransitive verb "higher" to come later, since its earliest citation for the form *highering* is from 1872 (the Tennyson quote) and its earliest citation for *highers* is apparently from 1905 ("The table highers and lowers for various depths of mortise," *Timber & Wood-working Machinery* 18 Nov. 871/2).

"Higher" as a verb is so rare that I found a grammar book that uses it as an example of a non-existent word:

> we cannot say *that roof needs highering*

– *[An Introduction to Functional Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=JM3KAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&dq=%22highering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqoZTMm_TPAhVG04MKHYjrBy0Q6AEISzAE#v=onepage&q=%22highering%22&f=false),* by M.A.K Halliday, revised by Christian M.I.M. Matthiessen, p. 51

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highering%2C%20rising&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chighering%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crising%3B%2Cc0) shows that compared to "rising," the frequency of "highering" is pretty much zero:

[image]